# How to insert values in more than two edittexts using sqllite?

Tags: android

I want to insert values in more than two edittexts. I tried it by myself by inserting the third entry into the databases and to display that entry but its not working.it gives error when i click any of the button 
Errors pops up and says "Unfortunately app has stopped working".Error also pops up on error log as "Unhandled event loop exception" Kindly help me out.Here's my code:

```
ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("Create table if not exists mytab(name varchar,sur_name varchar )");

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = ed1.getText().toString();
            String sur_name = ed2.getText().toString();
            ed1.setText("");
            ed2.setText("");

            db.execSQL("Insert into mytab values('" + name + "','"
                    + sur_name + "')");
            Toast.makeText(Text.this, "values insert successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select *from mytab", null);
            tv.setText("");
            c.moveToFirst();

            do {
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                String surname = c.getString(1);
                tv.append("Name:" + name + " and SurName:" + surname + "\n");
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When you say 'its not working', what does that mean? Is there an error? Is  the data just not saving?

Comment: it gives error when i click any of the button 
Errors pops up and says "Unfortunately app has stopped"

Comment: logcat doesnt show anything ...error pops up on error log as "Unhandled event loop exception"